# How to implement form authentication for metro apps c#,xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am trying to develop a metro style app where I have to authenticate the user with his/her Live ID (ex gmail or Hotmail) using Form authentication .Can I do it in metro apps ?If so how to implement it and any specific sites where I can get code .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Single sign-on for apps and websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826544.aspx)

> Because Windows 8 enables users to sign in to their devices by using a
>   Microsoft account, app developers can provide a single sign-on
>   experience across Windows Store apps and companion websites.

Comment: thanks for the reply .If possible can you please share some site URL's for reference ..

Comment: That site has lot of examples. please check